# Specifying Images Sizes in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, image

If I have the following :-

```
<asp:image height="54" width="54" runat="server" id="imgA" imageurl="/pic.jpg" />
```

when it get compiled, it comes out as :-

```
<img src="/pic.jpg" style="height:54;width=50;" id="imgA"/>
```

Whenever I put it through Google tools, it says to improve the page, I need to put the size which it expects it in the non-style format.  Is there anyway to force the .NET compiler to compile to the non-style format so the result is :-

```
<img src="/pic.jpg" height="54" width="50" id="imgA"/>
```

or is the only way is to use img rather than asp:image ?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

**CSS**

```
.img{
  height : 54px;
  width : 50px;
}
```

**.aspx**

```
<asp:image CssClass="img" runat="server" id="imgA" imageurl="/pic.jpg" />
```

Comment: Nope, Google Page Inside says  "The following image(s) are missing width and/or height attributes."  I used the method above with CssClass but it doesn't seem to accept it in CSS form, it has to be the old format.  The resulting html has to be in the format as per third example in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you think that your image would be at a certain size, then you need to resize your image to that size... I can't imagine that you load a file from 10MB to fit in a canvas of 50x50 px :=)